# Vibration not working in background mode (Ionic/capacitor))

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, android-vibration

I am working on a project in which the client needs vibration in background-mode.
The method

```
vibrator.vibrate()
```

is working when the screen is on and app is open. But when the screen is off or app is minimized (not killed), the vibration function not working. Anybody know the solution?

Comment: Are you using the Vibration Native Plugin method to vibrate?

Comment: Yes..But it works only when the screen is on and our app is foreground..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got how to get the background mode vibration in ionic app. Its possible using capacitor haptics vibration and foreground service plugins.

```
import {Haptics} from "@capacitor/haptics";
import { ForegroundService } from '@ionic-native/foreground-service/ngx';
...
constructor(private fg_service:ForegroundService){}
...
this.fg_service.start('App name', 'Service name', 'drawable/fsicon');
Haptics.vibrate({duration:500});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Native Plugin - Vibration doesn't have the vibrate in background mode functionality yet. Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration/issues/92) for the open issue in Github.

Comment: Is there anyway to create such functionality by editing plugins?

Comment: I don't know what functionality you are trying to do by using vibration but you can use Ionic FCM to achieve the vibrate function when app is killed or in background.